# Fresh install on SSD with Ubuntu and Windows Vista, using whole disk encryption for Ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot, encryption, ssd, trim

I would like to do a fresh install on a OCZ Vertex Plus R2 SSD 60GB drive I purchased on the cheap.  Since the AES-encryption looks like it may not work optimally for this drive, I would like to set up a dual-boot to Windows Vista (the only Windows copy I have for clean install purposes) and Ubuntu 12.04 with the best encryption scheme possible.  My plan is to have Windows around just in case I need to use a program that won't work with Wine and Ubuntu as my daily OS with all of my information secured in case the laptop is ever stolen or sold.  Although this setup will not provide a lot of space, I think I can squeeze both OSes and have enough for second-computer office tasks.  So, my questions are:

1. Which OS should I install first, Ubuntu or Vista?
2. Any special considerations when partitioning the drive?
3. How should I install Ubuntu to ensure full disk encryption for the Linux partition(s) and or my daily computing?
4. Is there a significant performance upgrade with doing a solo install of Ubuntu instead of a dual boot setup?  Will TRIM, for example, work correctly?
5. Are there any significant security concerns with going the route of a dual-boot, other than the fact that any activity on Windows may be fully recoverable if the drive is stolen or sold?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) Install windows first

2) I would recommend just encrypting your /home directory since this functionality is built directly into the installer and is easy for new users to setup.

3) See #2

4) No performance difference with dual-booting just avoid using WUBI.

5) Make sure your /home where all your user data is stored is encrypted.

Comment: With respect to #2, should I do whole disk encription using the Alternative method or something else?  Thanks!

Comment: It's up to you if you want. All of your users data and application preferences are stored in your /home/username directory. So most people just encrypt that. But as with everything in linux you have many choices. It's hard to say what's best for one user to the next. You have to try it and determine what works best for you.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is whether just encrypting the home directory is enough or if I should encrypt the entire disc using the LVM method advocated in http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/10/how-to-install-ubuntu-11-04-on-an-encrypted-lvm-file-system/ and http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/09/home-directory-and-full-disk-encryption-in-ubuntu-11-04/ when dealing with a dual-boot SSD scenario?